# Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value "XX" to data type int while sorting

Tags: asp.net, sql, sorting

I want to sort my grid view by title of article with a dropdownlist like below picture.
I connect my grid view to a dataSqlsouce.
but it gave me this error:
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value "XX" to data type int.
[image]

my Sql cod in datasqlsource is:

```
SELECT addtitle.title, 
       submitmanuscript.status, 
       addarticletype.type, 
       addarticletype.username                           AS Expr1, 
       addarticletype.articletype, 
       submitmanuscript.date, 
       submitmanuscript.articlenum, 
       addarticletype.articleid, 
       CONVERT (VARCHAR(10), submitmanuscript.date, 103) AS date1, 
       addarticletype.checkfinish, 
       rolinfo.* 
FROM   addarticletype 
       INNER JOIN addtitle 
               ON addarticletype.articleid = addtitle.articleid 
       INNER JOIN submitmanuscript 
               ON addarticletype.articleid = submitmanuscript.articleid 
       INNER JOIN rolinfo 
               ON addarticletype.username = rolinfo.username 
WHERE  ( addarticletype.articleid IN (SELECT articleid 
                                      FROM   addupload_4 AS AddUpload_4_1 
                                      WHERE 
         ( addarticletype.checkfinish = '0' )) ) 
       AND ( addarticletype.type = @Type ) 
ORDER  BY CASE 
            WHEN @order = 'AddArticleType.ArticleID' THEN addarticletype.articleid 
            WHEN @order = 'Title' THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR, title) 
            WHEN @order = 'family' THEN family 
            WHEN @order = 'AddArticleType.ArticleType' THEN 
            addarticletype.articletype 
          END
```

Can any body help me?

Comment: I use CONVERT(VARCHAR,Title) to make it nvarchar!

Comment: thank you, What is your suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is in your ORDER BY CASE statement -- you're trying to sort by ints and/or nvarchars and it won't allow for that:

See this fiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/db37b/1

You can resolve this by converting all sort values to nvarchar, although @Gordons answer seems more appropriate:

```
ORDER  BY CASE 
        WHEN @order = 'AddArticleType.ArticleID' THEN CONVERT(nvarchar,addarticletype.articleid) 
        WHEN @order = 'Title' THEN CONVERT(nvarchar, title) 
        WHEN @order = 'family' THEN CONVERT(nvarchar, family)
        WHEN @order = 'AddArticleType.ArticleType' THEN 
         CONVERT(nvarchar, addarticletype.articletype )
      END
```

You probably just need to use the CONVERT on the ArticleId field, but I went ahead and put it on all the fields since I didn't know their data types.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

A `case` statement has to choose one type to return.  The first `then` is a number which is causing the problem.

Just split the clauses into separate `case` statements:

```
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN @order = 'AddArticleType.ArticleID' THEN AddArticleType.ArticleID  end),
         (case WHEN @order = 'Title' then CONVERT(VARCHAR,Title) end),
         (case WHEN @order = 'family' THEN family end),
         (case WHEN @order = 'AddArticleType.ArticleType' THEN AddArticleType.ArticleType END)
```

Comment: I think the problem here are the commas in the order by -- add "ELSE 0" or some arbitray value to each of the CASE statements and it should work...

Comment: What error are you getting?  You should be able to have multiple expressions in an `order by`.  The lack of `else` clause is immaterial; it should just default to NULL.

Comment: @GordonLinoff -- my apologies, you are absolutely correct.  I don't see any issues with your code.